# Confluent Kafka missing methods for .NET

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am using Confluent.Kafka package v2.0.2 that I downloaded via NuGet in a .NET project in order to create a Kafka Consumer and I noticed that Confluent's docs ([this](https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.Consumer.html)  page for instance) include many methods that this package don't such as: Poll(), OnMessage(), ConsumeAsync() and many more. I am not a customer of Confluent.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

I tried to see source code of Consumer class and IConsumer interface and the above methods were declared there.

Answer (score 3):

The version of the documentation you're referring to is out of date.

Here are some links to current documentation:

1. [Confluent Docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/dotnet/current/overview.html#ak-dotnet)
2. [Current API Docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.html)